# executing same code in multiple pages with session variables

Tags: php, session-variables

I have teh code below that needs to be the same on 20+ pages. I would like to make it so if I have to change the code I would only have to do it once and not on every single page.

I have tried to use the Include and Require but the Session variables aren't populating correctly.

```
//Start session
  $session = new Session();
// check to see if $_SESSION['timeout'] is set
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout']) ) {
  $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
  if($session_life > $inactive) { 
    session_destroy(); 
    $_SESSION = array();
    header("Location: ../../managers.php"); 
    exit(); 
  }
}
if ( !$_SESSION['valid_user'] ) {
    session_destroy(); 
    $_SESSION = array();
    header("Location: ../../managers.php"); 
    exit();    
}
//update cookie informaiton
  $_sess_name = session_name();
  $_sess_id = session_id();
// Update cookie ;)
  setcookie($_sess_name, $_sess_id, time() + 900, "/", str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance. Please let me know if I need to clarify any information as well.

Comment: Is `session_start();` indeed loaded? 99% of OP's never post that. Only after do they say: *"Yes, it is loaded."*

Comment: Fred, I will not lie :) .. i had the session_start() before I called the function on the initial page load; moved it inside of the function ( as suggested in the answer below) in the 'included' page and all is **GREAT** now. Thank you and Konstantin for your reply too.

Comment: You're welcome. *Another happy ending* - cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in the beginning of your script

And then you can write to and read from $_SESSION array